# iterate through function arguments supposede to be lists python

Tags: python, function, types

I try to write a long program in python
the first part is:

```
def frequence(entranche):
podium = []
for item in entranche:
    scat = len(entranche)
    for indice in range (len(entranche)):

        if entranche[indice] == item:
            scat -= 1
        frequence = len(entranche) - scat
        podium = podium.append(frequence)
    plus_haute_frequence = max (podium)   
    return(plus_haute_frequence)
```

print(frequence(("Je suis né dans le béton Coincé entre deux maisons  Sans abri sans domicile" 
 ).split()))

**How would the program treat "entranche" as list?**

Comment: you have `lst` variable that has not been defined

Comment: Yes your right I'm sorry, the definitive form has been changed because I tried to change names of variables to lst hoping to resolve the problem but no matter...

Comment: `podium = podium.append(frequence)` is the same as `podium = None` . Try just `podium.append(...)`, without assigning it to podium.

Comment: On another note, what are you trying to accomplish with this function? Are you trying to build a frequence distribution of the words in the list `entranche`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call the `split` method.

```
entranche = poeme.split()
```

Answer (score 1):

`entranche = poeme.split` is a function, not a list. You forgot the parenthesis, which do the actual call to the function `entranche = poeme.split()` and returns a list.

Answer (score 1):

If `entranche` would be a list, you wouldn't see that error. So, check what `entranche` really is. Check its `type()`, or just `print` it.

You'll find your error here:

```
entranche = poeme.split
```

That should be:

```
entranche = poeme.split()
```

Comment: Please see the next response I writed.

Comment: sorry but I come back the type of entranche after the line of definition function is already. I get tangled and I feel that a good tutorial is necessary. Is that thomething for me?

Comment: @kouty: Sorry, but i don't understand what's your problem with `entranche` :-( Some code and the errors you get might help, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

there is noway to precise my question
Folowing xph I try this

```
def frequence(entranche):
    podium = []
    print("premier podium", type(podium))
    for item in entranche:
        print ("deuxieme podium", type(podium))
        scat = len(entranche)
        for indice in range (len(entranche)):            
            if entranche[indice] == item:
                scat -= 1
            frequence = len(entranche) - scat

        podium = podium.append(frequence)
        print("troisieme podium", type(podium))
        plus_haute_frequence = max(podium)   
    return(plus_haute_frequence)
print(frequence("Je suis né dans le béton Coincé entre deux maisons".split()))
```

and I get a big surprise!

```
premier podium <class 'list'>
deuxieme podium <class 'list'>
troisieme podium <class 'NoneType'>
```

What is iT??

Comment: I think it's not good to write another question as an answer. Just ask a new question, as this is a new problem - i guess your list-problem with `entranche`is fixed, now? Then just tick the most helpful answer, that would be nice. Now, i think your problem is  this: `troisieme podium <class 'NoneType'>` - right? It's because of `podium = podium.append(frequence)`. Just append the new value to your list, re-assigning the variable istn't correct here. Just do `podium.append(frequence)`.

Comment: Wonderfull I'll try to make a new question and nest it with your answer.